# VBA - Data string connection to Web Access Table on Sharepoint

Tags: web-services, excel, vba, sharepoint

I was wondering if it is possible to create a data connection through VBA connecting an Access 2010 table hosted on SharePoint 2010 and Excel 2010? if so what would the code look like? The code would need to be in vba for excel

Comment: [have you looked here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I've tried the access connection string and SharePoint connection string. Neither has worked for the Access web service yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my original post, I have found a work around and I hope this helps others. Here is the connection string needed to connect excel to a Access service table.

```
Sub LinkedSharePointList()

 ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
 Source:=Array("URL HERE", "TABLE NAME HERE", _
 "{GUID HERE}"), LinkSource:=True, Destination:=Range("A1")

End Sub
```

*** It is important to note that you must save the excel file as a 97-2003 .xls file.  The excel file will still run macros and save (though there will be an warning as you try to save the file, just check the don't remind me box).  Also, in order for the table to update to your access service table, you need to right click the table (in excel)-> table->synchronize to SharePoint list.

I also wrote a macro to update the access service table using a button control but did not include that here.  If you are unsure what your GUID is then import the table from access service to excel, under the data tab->connections->Properties->Definition and in the 'Command Text:' after  will be the GUID.

Comment: I would like to add that you can update and delete the table in both excel and Access services